# Can't run migrations after pushing to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm trying to push a newer version of my site to Heroku. After the push, the rake db:migrate seems to fail due to some missing table (the one I'm trying to create obviously).

`PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "specialisms" does not exist`

I've read various other threads advising to run db:reset and such, but this is a live environment, I'd rather not clear the DB.

Another option was to run migrations before pushing the new version. But this way the new migrations are not available on the server yet. So I'm a bit troubled what to try next.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you show what your migrations look like and the existing tables that they are referencing?

Comment: I'm actually a few migrations behind on production, so there are quite some. I think about 6-8 migrations. What is it exactly what you're looking for? Do you think something inside the migrations is causing this?

Comment: The strange thing is that the both the live version as the rake db:migrate fail with this error. I don't understand my db:migrate is failing with the same error,

Comment: @bo-oz, it might be the sequence of migration. One of the migration might be expecting to have `specialisms` table.

Comment: I found the issue. It was caused by some class methods I created for the specialism model. These were triggered in one of my migration files which was somehow causing the errors